# getting FlatFileParseException when there is empty line in my flat file when doing batch processing with spring-batch

Tags: spring-batch

i used  the below code for handling it:

```
<skippable-exception-classes>
   <includeclass="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
</skippable-exception-classes>
```

But what is the correct way to handle empty lines in flat file, to avoid seeing the `FlatFileParseException`, when processing with spring batch.

Comment: You say that you handled it using FlatFileParseException, but then you ask how to handle it.  Please state your goal, and any steps you've made to reach that goal.  Include code examples, and do please search for this topic on your own.

Comment: my goal is to avoid the exception when there is empty line in my flatfile.

Comment: Please include the exception, with full stack trace, so that we can see the details.

Comment: Have you investigated this bug ? https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1417 ? or this post on the spring-batch forum http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/54892-how-to-handle-blank-lines ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could accomplish what you're looking for with a custom `RecordSeparatorPolicy`.  You could strip out any empty lines via the `RecordSeparatorPolicy#preProcess` method and return true in the `RecordSeparatorPolicy#isEndOfRecord` once you have a record with text.  The only gotcha is that you'd have to do some trickery around the use case of if a file had blank lines at the end of the file but I think it's doable.